# Can I flatten a list containing dictionaries and lists of dictionaries within a list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a function that can return either a dictionary or a list of dictionary based on the argument passed. An MWE is provided below:

```
def do_something(condition: bool):
    if not condition:
        return {"foo": "bar"}
    return [{"foo": "bar"}, {"foo": "bar"}]

my_array = [False, False, True, False]

result = [do_something(i) for i in my_array]
print(result)
```

What I want to do is make it so that `result` contains a list of individual dictionaries rather than having some elements being a list of dictionary. So at the moment, the result of this code is:

```
[{'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}, [{'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}], {'foo': 'bar'}]']
```

But I want the result to be:

```
[{'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}]
```

Is there any way to achieve this result using a list comprehension or would I need to use a for loop and append to the list as I go?

The only idea I had was to see if there was a way to unpack the list using the * operator but that doesn't work:

```
return *[{"foo": "bar"}, {"foo": "bar"}  # Can't used starred expression here.
```

**UPDATE**
I've marked an accepted answer in this thread, but I achieved the same result by using `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`

So my code now reads:

```
import itertools  # Extra import I needed
result = list(
    itertools.chain.from_iterable([do_something(i) for i in my_array])
)
```

Comment: Generally, if you determine a solution to your own question, you should add this result as an additional answer, rather than editing it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
from collections import Iterable

def flatten(lst):
    for elm in lst:
        if isinstance(elm, Iterable) and not isinstance(elm, (str, bytes, dict)):
            yield from flatten(elm)
        else:
            yield elm
        
l = [{'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}, [{'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}], {'foo': 'bar'}]
flatten = list(flatten(l))
```

Output: [{'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}]

If you don't want the *dict* objects be present in the flattened list, then you can remove *dict* from the isinstance() checking.

Comment: I ended up using `itertools.chain.from_iterable` instead, but this accomplishes the same thing, so I'll mark this as the answer. I'll update my question to show my solution too.

Answer (score 1):

If your Python is 3.8 or above:

```
def do_something(condition: bool):
    if not condition:
        return {"foo": "bar"}
    return [{"foo": "bar"}, {"foo": "bar"}]

my_array = [False, False, True, False]

[(result := []) if i is None 
else [result.append(do_something(j)) if not j 
else result.extend(do_something(j)) 
for j in i] 
for i in (None, my_array)]

print(result) 
#[{'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}, {'foo': 'bar'}]
```